# Loop until user input matches requirements

Tags: python, while-loop, compare

I'm coding Python with my son and we'd like to ask the user for a choice ("t" or "d") in order to proceed.
In lack of GoTos I thought using `while` would be a great idea, but we weren't able to code it successfully.

Our code:

```
while (answer != "t" and answer != "d"):
    answer = input(question)
```

`question` is a variable containing the question (surprise).
It seems that `answer` - which should hold the input's result from the while-loop - is never set, because no matter what the user enters, I'm prompted again.

Comment: Assuming that you initialized `answer` before the `while` loop, your code should work as you describe.

Answer (score 1):

Your code works.
You just need to make sure {answer} was already defined before the loop.

```
question="hi "
answer=input(question)
while (answer != "t" and answer != "d"):
    answer = input(question)
print("GOOD !")
```

is working for example

Comment: Hi, this is pretty mich how our code looks - doesn't work though :-|

Answer (score 0):

`goto` is a blast from the past! Here's one way to do it in Python:

```
question  = "Enter answer:  "
while True:
    answer = input(question).lower()
    if answer in ["t", "d"]:
        break
# have entered t,T,d or D; if only t and d are allowed remove .lower()
print(answer)
```

The answer avoids repeating code (input expressions) and shows how `in` can be used for multiple checking without numerous == or != conditionals (`not in` can be similarly used in other circumstances). The `while True: ... break` construction is often used in Python.

Comment: We'll give it a try as soon as my son returns from school...

Comment: Works, thanks a lot 